# Raspberry Pi 2 B+ Doesn't have all it memory available after touchscreen installation

Tags: memory, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

**In short**
What file(s) or program(s) controls how much memory is found and can be used by your OS. In my case Raspbian on the Raspberry Pi 2 B+ (kernel version 3.18)?

---

**More info**
I tried to install a touchscreen.
For this I had to replace:
- `kernel.img`
- `kernel7.img`
- `bootcode.bin`
- `start.elf`
- `/lib/firemwire`
- `/lib/modules`
- `/opt/vc`

Website: http://engineering-diy.blogspot.nl/2013/01/adding-7inch-display-with-touchscreen.html?showComment=1430746655545

Not all files in `firemwire`, `modules` and `vc` had to be replaced but most of them did. But now I only have about 120mb of memory I can use! :(

To solve it I ran `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` and (I think) this 'overwrote' some or all of the files I replaced before.

My memory came back to 800+ but I lost the touchscreen functionality.
Then I replaced the touchscreen files again. Now my touchscreen works again, but still only about 120mb of memory.

I think some file, files or settings used for the touchscreen prevent my Raspbian installation to use all it's memory.

How can I change this and use all of the Rpi2's memory and the touchscreen?
Or more specifically: What file or settings should I check and maybe change to get back all the memory?

---

**Raspi-config**
It's not a problem of memory-split (as far as I understand). Changing this value in the raspi-config doesn't appear to have any effect on the memory available.

---

**Memory check**
I used `htop` and `free -m` to check how much memory I have.
Both tell the same value of about 120mb.

Comment: Any ideas? Even the smallest thing might help! :)

Comment: Well done for solving it yourself. Next time, I would recommend asking this at the [Unix/Linux Stackexchange site](http://Unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: And you may want to post your solution below in the answer section and mark it accepted so the question no longer appears as unanswered :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!**
The `start.elf` file shouldn't be replaced! Then all the memory will be available!
In the time I was waiting I just experimented with the files in the boot partition and stumbled upon the solution!